# Messages block not using theme template

Tags: magento-1.7, template, magento-enterprise, core

I am trying to change the phtml file for the messages block. I found in the base theme `template/core/messages.phtml` and copied that over to my theme and made the changes. My changes didn't show so I tried modifying the source in the base file and the changes still were not applied.

Where is this template file located or how can I overwrite it?

Comment: Hey kel did you figure this one out in the end?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately the `core/messages.phtml` file is not used for the messages you're speaking of. All the HTML is generated on the Block level in `Mage_Core_Block_Messages`.

The good news is you can control the tags used in the messages by calling these functions:

1. `Mage_Core_Block_Messages::setMessagesFirstLevelTagName($tagName)`
2. `Mage_Core_Block_Messages::setMessagesSecondLevelTagName($tagName)`

An example of implementing this would be to modify your `layout/page.xml` file by finding the lines that read:

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
<block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
```

And changing them to something like:

```
        <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages">
            <action method="setMessagesFirstLevelTagName"><tagName>div</tagName></action>
            <action method="setMessagesSecondLevelTagName"><tagName>span</tagName></action>
        </block>
        <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages">
            <action method="setMessagesFirstLevelTagName"><tagName>div</tagName></action>
            <action method="setMessagesSecondLevelTagName"><tagName>span</tagName></action>
        </block>
```

And if you need even more control then you could override the block in your own module and customise the `getHtml()` and `getGroupedHtml()` methods.

Happy styling!

Comment: I'm constantly amazed at what can be accomplished via layout xml actions

Comment: Yeah they're great - you can call any block method through layout XML just the same as you would in a `*.phtml` file with `$this->doSomething()` or `$this->setSomeData('foobar')`.

Comment: How do you add css classes? I would like to apply twitter bootstrap styles